# Saving bound service state before it is killed by Android

Tags: android, service

When an adroid service is killed by the OS (due to low memory or low power). Does the service get notified before it is killed? Does the onDestroy() callback get called?

Our main concern is our ability to save the state of a service before it is killed. We know that the service may be restarted by the system once the resources are available, but what is the recommended way to save the state of the service before it gets killed?

Attached is a sequence diagram of our understanding of the force close process of a bound service, it includes what we would like to happen.

Comment: I thinks (but am not sure) that you'll get an onDestroy() call when the system kills your app. But you should be aware there will be times that your application gets killed and you don't get any callback (i.e. user kills with task killer) So you'll want to make sure this doesn't create a serious problem within your system.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the service get notified before it is killed? Does the onDestroy() callback get called?

Possibly. It is not guaranteed.

> Our main concern is our ability to save the state of a service before it is killed.

A service should not have state that is only represented in RAM. You should be persisting the state as the state changes (e.g., use a database).

Comment: onDestroy() will never get called if it is killed for memory, just like Activity.

Comment: Having to persist all state changes to flash is unacceptable, as it requires greatly increased battery usage and decreases the lifetime of the flash.

Answer (score 0):

From API level 14 (ICS) onwards, android os notifies the service if the service is being removed by the user and also if the system decides `that it is a good time for a process to trim unneeded memory from its process`. Here's a [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the [`onTrimMemory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onTrimMemory(int)) metod from Service. You will receive an `int level` that will tell you the severity of the memory shortage.

```
TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW

TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL
```

The OS will inform that the memory is running low and it might kill your app's process.

Here its a good place to save to persistent storage (Room Db, SharedPreferences) the data you don't want to lose.